# Transfer database value to excel in a specific cell

Tags: database, excel, gridview

To start with, I have no idea yet even a code on how to do this. To make things clearer, I want to transfer a database value to excel to a specific location. Lets say I have a saved template (excel) naming RISK.xls. I have 4 tables that has a common column named riskId in which i want to get a specific value to be transferred. Let's put it this way,

Table 1 in database(Department):i want to transfer column department where riskId = 50(sample)
Table 2 in DB(Rate): I want to transfer column inherent where riskId = 50(sample)
table 3 in DB(treatment): i want to transfer column description where riskId = 50
table 4 in DB(strategy): i want to transfer column details where risjId = 50

now i want to transfer selected value in table to be transferred in my excel. Here goes:

Selected Value in Table 1 transferred to excel cell A5.
Selected Value in Table 2 transferred to excel cell B5.
Selected Value in Table 3 transferred to excel cell C5.
Selected Value in Table 4 transferred to excel cell D5.

Plus this option: those tables are related to each other so if in excel table 1 value has multiple table 2 value and each item in multiple table 2 value has its own multiple value which is in table 3 and so on. So one A5 = B5 to B10(sample) and b5 = C5 to c10) like this.

Hope anyone can help me with this.

Thanks and feel free to ask me about my problem.

Comment: try something first ..

Comment: string filename = "Risk House Report.xls";
            System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);
            DataGrid dgGrid = new DataGrid();
            dgGrid.DataSource = dt;
            dgGrid.DataBind();                                                                      Here's where the gridview was transferring was done

Comment: As what I said I do not know where to start since this was my first time to work such project.

Comment: Please don't post code in comments to your post; [edit] your post to add it there, where it can be easily seen (and properly formatted). Also, please do some research here regarding reading and writing data to Excel, as there are dozens (if not hundreds) of similar questions that a little research on your part could find. Once you've done that and actually tried to write the data and run into problems, you can post the **specific** code that's not working and ask a question about that code. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could query the database using the "External Data" feature in Excel and create a specific SQL statement that will return the values in a specific worksheet. After that's done, you can reference what's in those cells using formulas.

Check this out to get you started:

http://www.spreadsheetsmadeeasy.com/excel-create-pivot-table-using-sql/